# Is it possible for symfony2 to create a default form to match a Doctrine entity?

Tags: symfony

If I've got a model with some fields in it, is it possible for Symfony's form builder to introspect the fields and generate a form that contains all of those fields?

It seems that I'm repeating myself by having to create the entity and then create a form telling it to add all of the fields of the entity again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have a look at this:

```
symfony-standard ➤ ./app/console help doctrine:generate:form                                                                       
Usage:
 doctrine:generate:form entity

Aliases: generate:doctrine:form
Arguments:
 entity  The entity class name to initialize (shortcut notation)

Help:
 The doctrine:generate:form command generates a form class based on a Doctrine entity.

 php app/console doctrine:generate:form AcmeBlogBundle:Post
```